# Cannot create VSTO Excel 2016 workbook customization in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, vsto, visual-studio-2017, excel-2016

I am unable to create a VSTO Workbook level or Template level Excel 2016 (16.0.7726.1049 32-bit) customization in Visual Studio Community 2017 (V4.6.01055).

What I get is a Folder structure like:

```
ExcelWorkbook1
  .vs
    ExcelWorkbook1
      v15
```

All empty except the root folder contains "ExcelWorkbook1.sln" and the v15 folder contains ".suo" files.

VS can create and run an Excel VSTO Add-in no problem but it cannot create Word Document level or Template Level customizations - the same folder structure occurs.

I have checked all the questions on this site (most of which refer to much older versions of Excel/VS) plus general searches across the web to no effect.

When opening older VSTO projects (2007) they open fine *but* if I try to open a worksheet in VS I get "Excel designer cannot be activated". These older projects still work in their release modes (I can't recompile them because the interface in a depended on project has changed and I can't open the workbook to fix it).

Within Excel Add-ins are not blocked in the trust center. Active .com add-ins include VS 2007, VS 2015 and VS 2017. I have turned off all .com add-ins except VS 2017 - the outcome is the same.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both VS and Office.

Help.